# Remove excess padding from text widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

The text widget is wrapped in a row with Expanded and a sized box with a height set to provide space from lower widget.

```
  Row(children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.favorite,
          color: Colors.grey,
          size: 24.0,
        )),
    Expanded(
      child: Text(
        "Dashboard",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: SizedBox(height: 10),
    )
  ]),
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question?

Comment: What layout are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Text doesn't have padding, are you talking about margin between the icon and the text? If so, then you probably shouldn't be using `Expanded`. 

`Expanded` stretches and uses the extra space between your row's children.

Comment: im trying to have text beside an icon but there is too much space between the two

Comment: ok so if i cant use expanded then how do I get them in the same row?

Answer (score 1):

Like @Daniel says, `Expanded` will add extra space to your widget. Here the [documentation excerpt of Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html):

> A widget that expands a child of a Row, Column, or Flex so that the
> child fills the available space.
>
> Using an Expanded widget makes a child of a Row, Column, or Flex
> expand to fill the available space along the main axis (e.g.,
> horizontally for a Row or vertically for a Column). If multiple
> children are expanded, the available space is divided among them
> according to the flex factor.

So, you need to remove the `Expanded` part for your `Icon`.

Here the sample with removed Expanded from Icon add added padding (ignore the color):

[image]

Here the updated code:

```
  Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Row(children: [
      Icon(
        Icons.favorite,
        color: Colors.grey,
        size: 24.0,
      ),
      SizedBox(width: 5), // Give some space to icon.
      Expanded(
        child: Text(
          "Dashboard",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: SizedBox(height: 10),
      )
    ]),
  ),
```

You can use `SizedBox(width: 5)` to add extra space from your Icon.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0),
            child: Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.grey, size: 24.0),
          ),
          Text(
              "Dashboard",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
            ),
          
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

That should give you the desired outcome

Use `Padding` on the bottom of `Row` to give you that space you desire from widget below. As stated in the comments `Expanded` will take all available space.